# AWS DynamoDB client best practice (MVC app)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working to port some data access to dynamo DB in a high-traffic app. A bit of background - the app collects a very high volume of data, and some specific tables were causing performance issues in a traditional DB. So with a bit of re-design and some changes to the data layout we have been able to make them fit the DynamoDB niche nicely.

My question is around the use/creation of the client object. The SDK docs suggest it is better to create one client and share it amongst multiple threads, so in my repository implementation  I have the client defined as a lazy singleton. This means it will be created once and all requests will share the same client (currently around 4000 requests per minute, but likely to grow massively as we come out of beta and start promoting the product).

Does anyone have any experience of making the AWS SDK scale?

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1):

When you create one client and share it with multiple threads, only one thread can use the client at one point of time in some SDK.

Definitely if you create separate clients for different threads, it is going to slow down the process.

So I would suggest you to take a middle approach here,

> > Maximize the HTTP connection pooling size, so that more number of clients are allowed to be created.
> >
> > And then you follow the sharing of client objects.

Batch operation can be used for .Net aws sdk

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BatchOperationsORM.html

Comment: Thanks for this - can you confirm that this is definitely the case with the .NET SDK?

Comment: @ItalianJob - This was a case with Java and PHP too I think..for .net we have an option to use batch job. Please see the edit, if that helps..